Do you need to include a license file?
Can a project just add a note in README that it's released on a particular license (with a link to the website that contain the license) or the file with the license need to be included with the project to be considered Open Source?

Each open source license specifies how to use it. You need to read the license you care about and follow it. For example, the MIT License says:

The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.

so you must do that, a note in the README does not fulfil that requirement.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It's true that licenses tell you how to apply them. Either it's included in the list of conditions as it is for the BSD and MIT licenses, or it is specified in the appendix to the license as it is for the GPL, LGPL and Apache licenses.
GPL and Apache specify a notice to be put into the header of every source file to make it clear. Both these notices include a URL to the license. The drawback is that these notices are relatively long, perhaps as long as the whole MIT or BSD license.
Even then, you are not strictly required to follow the requirements in the appendices to the licenses. SPDX license identifiers were invented for this purpose, so that you can put your copyright notice and the SPDX license identifier to the header of every source file. That would be short and simple.
However, the main point I want emphasize is that the license must be clear and unambiguous to the potential licensee. If the licensing terms are unclear, potential licensees would likely avoid using the software.
So, to make it clear and unambiguous to the potential licensee, I would recommend to follow these steps, for a single license (i.e. assuming it's not multi-licensed):

Put a copy of the whole license text into a file called LICENSE or COPYING at the top level folder of your repo. That's the first place I would look, if it were me.
For most licenses (MIT, BSD, GPL, LGPL, Apache), put two lines at the top of every source file in comments, where the first line is the copyright statement, and the second line is the SPDX license identifier.
For the MPL license, you need to follow the source file header notice in Exhibit A of the license, as it is a file-level copyleft license.
For the Apache license, you can also put your copyright notice into a file called NOTICE at the top level folder of the repo, but this is not mandatory.


Awesome, thanks for your explanation.
